# Is replication possible on two different domains?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I am implementing a database replication between different geograhical locations where each one is on a different domain. After going through all the process, when I start the agent it runs and stops.

When I look at the details it shows:

```
Error messages:
The process could not connect to Subscriber 'Mydomain\myusername'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20084)

Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 18452)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replication across non-trusted domains or workgroups can be done using Windows Authentication by configuring **pass-through authentication**.

Create a local Windows account on both the Publisher and Subscriber that has the same username and password.  Use this account for the replication agent process account and have the connections to the publisher, distributor, and/or subscriber impersonate this account.  Ensure the account has the permissions required in [Replication Agent Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).

This approach is covered in the section ***Use Windows Authentication to Set Up Replication Between Two Computers Running SQL Server in Non-Trusted Domains*** in [HOW TO: Replicate Between Computers Running SQL Server in Non-Trusted Domains or Across the Internet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321822).

Comment: i following this link you provided.Am still having change to make the process connect to the subcriber.I create the same account with the same password on both domain

Comment: They need to be local Windows accounts on both Publisher and Subscriber.  Not domain accounts.

Comment: I did exactly that.But the process could still not access the subcriber. am trying this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911841)

Comment: What does that link have to do with anything?  Please post exact error messages back here.

Comment: when i view syncronization status on the subcriber it say:

Comment: Process could not connect to the ddnserver.i click start agent on the replication monitor from the subcriber it display:The agent could not be started.
Additional information:
An exception occurred while exucuting a Transact-sql statement or batch.
Sqlagent error.Request to run job
SM-PC2 Schoo_dbprist_publication  DDNSERVER(from user sa refused because the job is already running from a request by user sa
(change database context to school_db.Error:22022

Comment: The job will not start because it is already running.  Right-click the job -> Stop job.  Then try to synchronize. Please post the result back here.

Comment: ,it works now.Syncrozination is taking place and the agent now is running

Answer (score 2):

This is failing because the two domains do not trust each other. Because of that, a process executing under an account in the one domain cannot use windows authentication to connect to a SQL Server in the other domain. To get around this, you have three options:

1. Create a trust relationship between the two domains.
2. Use path-through authentication. (Create a windows account with the same user name and password on all machines in your topology.)
3. Use SQL Authentication for cross domain connections when setting up replication.

My [replication stairway articles](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72401/) give a step by step walkthrough of setting up SQL Server Replication and includes detailed information about the different security credentials used by the different processes. While the Stairway is not a step by step guide for setting up a cross domain installation, you should find enough information in there to get you past this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to setup connectivity between these two servers on different domain with the help of the network administrator and update DNS entry as well.

1. Create SQL login with same password on both server
2. Make sure to connect SQL Server from one server to other server and vice versa using SQL login.
3. Create publication on source server using agent security account and define articles
4. Create PUSH subscription so that both snapshot/transaction agent and distribution agent will run on publisher.while configuring make sure that connection to subscriber should be with SQL login created on step1.
5. Verify Replication monitor and confirm everything working fine.